# How do I make semantic ui pages responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui for developing web pages.
I want them to be responsive. I tried to open web pages on my phone but the size of the grid changes to minimum and that doesn't look good.
What changes should I do to my code ?

```
<div class="ui six wide column
 segment" id="logBox"
 style="background-color: #F1F0FF;">

    <div class="ui centered
                header"><h1>Log-In to your 
    account</h1>
                   </div>

        <form class="ui form">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon
                input">
                <i class="user icon"></i>
                <input type="text"
        placeholder="Email-id" >
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon   

                     input">
                    <i class="lock icon"></i>
                    <input type="password"     

            placeholder="Password">



           </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
  @media only screen and (max-   
         width: 640px){

         #logBox{
            width:100%;
         }
       }
```

Comment: Could you please provide us some code so we can see what to actually change? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would after a certain breakpoint make elements full width and remove any floats. Generally all your grid elements have a common class, like 'ui' in the above case, you could use that like so:

```
.ui {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I got the solution. I just removed the 'six wide column' class  and kept the ui segment class and added a breakpoint with max-width:738. This solved my problem

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution :)